# How can send json in telnet to PHP socket

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

How can i send a json encode string in telnet .

Im using **SOCKET** and connecting to socket via :

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
```

So how i can send request that obtain below code requrments ?

my php code is :

```
        $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
        $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
        $user_id = $tst_msg->id; //sender id
        $reciver_id = $tst_msg->rec; //sender name
        $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
```

Comment: The PHP code you've provided doesn't refer to sockets anywhere.

Comment: The PHP code you've provided appears to attempt to receive JSON rather than send it :-?

Comment: Please head to the [PHP: Sockets](http://php.net/sockets) documentation to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send your message like this :

```
{"id" : "" , "rec" : "" , "message" : ""}
```